# Counting the number of times my location has been changed

Tags: android

I'm reliantly new to android and I wanted to make a simple location app using the gps. I've done all this but I wanted to log the amount times it updated and displayed a new location (this being longitude and latitude). Because I am used to Visual Basic logic tells me that I can get the new location variable to add 1 to a new variable and then display that variable. is there any android equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/42.html) how to use LocationApi in android.You can increment a variable in onUpdate method to find how many times your location is changed